# Why is it dangerous to render user-generated HTML or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, security, sandbox, jinja2

I don't know if this is really dangerous, but, as Google does it with its HTML and Javascript served from Google Apps Script (as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/restrictions), they use [Caja Compiler](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/) to "sanitize and sandbox HTML").

I was wondering if was there anything bad that could happen if I let users edit HTML *with Jinja2 templates giving them access to some server-side variables* that would be rendered sometime later. What bad can happen?

Obs: I don't care if the user HTML will be ugly or if it will destroy the rest of the page.

Comment: If you site provides no useful information to users, does not collects any information from users, have solid server side code (i.e. no SQL injection) and have clearly awful domain name there is really not much of a problem... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allowing end users to edit HTML or JavaScript can lead to your site being vulnerable to XSS - https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS).

If users view the content other users have created, their scripts could be compromising cookie values or the user session by sending the values to the attacker's server.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how to prevent this?

Comment: It is good practise to use the `HttpOnly` flag on cookies (https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly) but if you are allowing users to edit HTML/script on your system you need to assess if there are any risks or sensitve information available in the page outside of cookie values. You can mitigate the risks by only allowing particular subdomains to contain edited HTML/script (e.g. foo.example.com) so these script will not be able to access any information on your main www.example.com domain due to the Same Origin Policy. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Answer (score 0):

Bad things can happen with HTML; worse things can happen with most templating engines, including Jinja2. Like arbitrary code execution. That’s why there’s a [sandbox](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/sandbox/).

Comment: How? I can't see where can be arbitrary code execution with HTML. It is just a string.

Comment: So it is secure to use Jinja2 in this way? Their sandbox makes my server invulnerable when rendering user-submitted templates?

Comment: @GiovanniP: There can’t be server-side code execution with static HTML, but Jinja2 isn’t just HTML… and I’ve never used that sandbox, but if they say so.