# using text as formula and replacing variables

Tags: javascript

I have a formula that's stored as text.  I get this value from a div, but for the purpose of this question I will simply assign the value manually.

```
price_formula = "100.00 + (pages-24)/4 * 25.00"
```

Now my aim is to replace `pages` with a numeric value and then do the Math on this formula and output the result.

Here's what I've tried:

```
price_formula = "150.00 + (pages-24)/2 * 30.00";
price_formula = price_formula.replace('pages', 32);
alert(price_formula); // outputs "150.00 + (32-24)/2 * 30.00)"
alert(Math.floor(price_formula)); // outputs "NaN"
```

How can I use the price_formula string as an actual formula?

Comment: You'd want to use `eval` here, but using `eval` is dangerous. (Python, but relevant: http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)

Comment: But for your reference: `eval("150.00 + (32-24)/2 * 30.00")`

Comment: Thank you, Casey. That is exactly what I was looking for.  You should add it as an answer, not just a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[This can be super dangerous](http://24ways.org/2005/dont-be-eval/) and you should [be careful with user-generated content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19633533/2456258).**

A string is not a number ([`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN)) -- so you can't perform math methods on it (like [`Math.floor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor)).

You *can* read the string as JavaScript and evaluate it with [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval):

```
var priceFormula = "150.00 + (pages-24)/2 * 30.00";
var price = eval( priceFormula.replace(/pages/g, 32) );
```

Comment: Thanx.  I will look into it.  At least I have something to work with, and I learnt something new.  Never. Stop. Learning.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply change **"pages"** to any desired value using `replace()` function like this:

```
price_formula = "100.00 + (pages-24)/4 * 25.00";
price_formula=price_formula.replace('pages','your value here');
```

Comment: Thanx. I updated my question with your solution.  Although I can now replace the "pages" in the string, I still can't use it as a formula.  Can you help?